# React: Hiding/Showing an element while hiding the rest of the similar elements

Tags: reactjs

I have a recipe creator that creates recipes and also lists their ingredients. I want it to only show the Recipe name and it's div it's inside of, but when you click it, it reveals the ingredients section. If any other sections are open I want it to also close them.

I've tried a couple solutions with state but haven't come up with a solid solution. I could probably do it with jQuery but I've heard it's not good practice to use React and jQuery so I'd rather do it properly.

This is the full app: https://github.com/jeffm64/recipe-box2/tree/master/src/components

The recipe boxes are rendered through .map in the main app render function as shown here:

```
{Recipes.map(function(item, key) {
                    return <RecipeBox recipe={Recipes} name={item.name} ingredients={item.ingredients} order={item.order} key={key} generalUpdate={genUpdate}  />;
})}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revealing just the one component's ingredients will be easier. Closing the rest will be a little trickier.

**Revealing ingredients** - Without Redux, you could add a state property `isOpen`. When you click on a button in that component it should change the state property `isOpen` to true. Hide/show the ingredients based on that state property value, which you can do in the markup (shown below) or with a class and a CSS rule.

```
<div key={1}>
  showIngredients = () => { this.setState({isOpen: true}) }
  <button onClick={this.showIngredients}>Show ingredients</button>
  {this.state.isOpen && <div>Ingredients list</div>}
</div>
```

**Hiding other ingredients** - This is a bit trickier and will require a different kind of solution. You'll need to define a method in a parent component that sets the state of all child components. Note the `key` in the component above. If each child has a unique key, and the parent defines a state property of `selectedKey`, you could do something like this:

```
// parent
revealChild = (key) => {this.setState(selectedKey: key)}
...
<div>
  {children.map((child) => {
    return <Child onReveal={this.revealChild} key={child.key} isSelected={this.state.selectedKey == child.key}/>
  })}
</div>

// child
handleReveal = () => this.props.onReveal(this.props.key)
showIngredientsClass = () => this.props.isSelected ? 'visible' : 'hidden'
showButtonClass = () => this.props.isSelected ? 'hidden' : 'visible'
...
<button onClick={handleReveal} className={this.showButtonClass()}>Show ingredients</button>
<div className={this.showIngredientsClass()}>
  My ingredients
</div>
```

Comment: For the first solution wouldn't having a state make it apply to every box where setting it to true makes them all open?

Comment: State is local to an instance of a component. If you have 3 `ChildItem`s in a list, each will have a different `this.state` object. So in example one, opening item 2 would only change the state object for item 2.

Comment: Ah that makes a lot more sense. I guess I was just trying to figure out how to include state in the main app as I thought I read somewhere that state in multiple areas was bad practice. I may have misread though.

Comment: State in multiple areas can definitely get hairy. Adopting some form of [flux architecture](https://facebook.github.io/flux/) like [redux](http://redux.js.org/) is a key part of keeping sane with state. Solution 1 in my answer is often done in local state, but solution 2 is generally better done with something like redux. That said, redux really complicates things before it makes them better.

Comment: Also "state in multiple areas" is not a bad practice when done correctly. Putting all your state in one big state tree has some high costs.

Comment: Yeah I haven't dove into Redux but did read about a tutorial for it one time and it definitely seems a bit difficult. I plan on learning that once I feel comfortable enough with React in general.